# What is an initializer in arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm learning arrays in C++. I created an array and I got an error:

> too many initializers in char [5].

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char myName[6][5] = {{'A', 'd', 'i', 't', 'y', 'a'},
                       {'S', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'h'}};
  cout << "The 1st letter in the 1st array is " << myName[0][0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I replace `char myName[6][5]` with `myName[6][6]`, the error is not there even if the array has 5 letters.

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: `char myName[6][5]` does not declare an array of two sub-arrays, the first one containing 6 values, the second one containing 5 values. That's not how C++ works. This declares six sub-arrays, five values each. Since your first sub-array contains six values, instead of five, the compiler is telling you that you got it wrong.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding 2D arrays. You have declared an array with 6 elements, where each element is itself a 5 element 1D array of `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration

```
char myName[6][5]
```

declares an array of *six* arrays of five characters. It's not two arrays of 6 and 5 characters (respectively). You have the arrays `myName[0]` to `myName[5]`.

Since each sub-array in `myName` is only five characters, it's asy to understand why you get an error since the first element `myName[0]` is initialized with *six* elements.

And if you want to use *strings*, then first of all you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), as in

```
std::string myNames[] = { "Aditya", "Singh" };
```

Or if you're not allowed to use `std::string`, create an array of arrays where each sub-array is long enough to fit the longest string:

```
char myNames[][7] = { "Aditya", "Singh" };
```

Note that the size if `7`, because strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings, and that *null-terminated* is an extra character that also needs space. That means a string of six characters needs space for seven to fit the terminator.

Comment: But in this video: https://youtu.be/Rub-JsjMhWY?t=898, he created the array using the same method and he didn't get any error. Can you tell me how I can create two arrays, from which I can get the first letter of my name and surname?

Comment: @SanjaySingh That's exactly what the last definition does, give you two arrays containing the names specified.